# How to prove that $n-1$ dimensions are insufficient to span an $n$ dimension vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A question from my Linear Algebra textbook asked

> Find a basis of the set of symmetric 3x3 matrices.

I found a basis of 6 matrices. 3 where the identity matrix 'split up' into three matrices. The other 3 where the symmetric elements of a 3x3 matrix.
So the first would be:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1  &0 \\ 
 1&0  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I can prove that if the basis had 7 elements they would be linearly dependent but how do I show that 5 elements would be insufficient?

For this question I 'guessed' the basis, in general what is the best strategy for finding a basis (not knowing the dimension beforehand) and how would one go about proving that $n-1$ elements are insufficient to span the vector space, or is there not a general approach?

Comment: Once you have a set of $k$ linearly independent vectors in $V$, then you can immediately say that $\dim(V)\geq k$.

Comment: About your title: you cannot «prove the dimension of a vector space», you can *compute* it. One proves propositions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your six matrices (call them $M_1$ through $M_6$), and solve the equation

$$x_1\cdot M_1+\ldots+x_6\cdot M_6=0$$

You can easily show that $x_1=\ldots=x_6=0$. This shows that the six matrices are linearly independent, so any basis must be of at least size six. Five matrices are insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $\;A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(\Bbb F)\;,\;\;\Bbb F\;$ some field, is symmetric iff $\;a_{ij}=a_{ji}\;,\;\;\forall\;1\le i,j\le n\;$ , and from here it follows at once that a symmetric $\;n\times n\;$ matrix is uniquely and completely determined by its values on its main diagonal *and the diagonals above it*, and there are

$$n+(n-1)+(n-2)+\ldots+2+1=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

entries on those diagonals, and thus this is the dimension of this space.

In case $\;n=3\;$ you get $\;\frac{3\cdot4}2=6\;$, so that if you already found six generating symmetric matrices (or equivalently: six linearly independent symmetric matrices), then you've already found a basis for you space.

If you want to know how to choose a basis, do as you did: put $\;1\;$ on some entry over the main diagonal or above it and zero in all the rest, and complete to a symmetric matrix, and repeat for each entry on the diagonal or above it.